# Подключить Visual Studio 2012 к Mysql

Tags: mysql, .net, c++-cli, visual-studio-2012

Код подключения к базе

```
String^ constring=L"server=127.0.0.1;username=root;password=password;database=my_db";
```

[image: Ошибка]

Подскажите пожалуйста, как исправить?

Comment: [MySQL connection strings](https://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql/). Какой именно провайдер используете?

Comment: Connector/Net 6.9.12

Comment: поставил Connector 6.6.5 -помогло. Получается Коннекторы начиная с версии 6.7 не поддерживают VS 2012